# Ambiguous [store] tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

Tag info for [store](/questions/tagged/store) is:

> A store is a data repository of a set of integrated objects. These objects are modeled using classes defined in database schemas. Data store includes not only data repositories like databases, it is a more general concept that includes also flat files that can store data.

Whereas, info for [datastore](/questions/tagged/datastore) is:

> A datastore is a generic term for a system which stores data. The term datastore includes RDBMS systems, NoSQL systems, memory based systems, flat files, spreadsheets to name just some examples. A given datastore may provide a rich toolset for storing and retrieving data (RDBMS)

Both look similar to me. Also [store](/questions/tagged/store) seems ambiguous as there are [app-store](/questions/tagged/app-store), [mac-app-store](/questions/tagged/mac-app-store), [blobstore](/questions/tagged/blobstore) and others.

Variety of questions are tagged under [store](/questions/tagged/store), such as

1. [Store image in variable, echo later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396693/store-image-in-variable-echo-later)
2. [fastest way to store data from sensors in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490923/fastest-way-to-store-data-from-sensors-in-java)
3. [iphone app submission for iOS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479478/iphone-app-submission-for-ios-6-0)

Should [store](/questions/tagged/store) be made a synonym of [datastore](/questions/tagged/datastore)? I guess not without manually retagging all questions. What is your take on this tag?

Comment: Store is too general. Probably should be retagged to appropriate tags and remove this tag